# What is the force on a block if another block sits on it?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, free-body-diagram

So imagine there is a Block A on top of a block B on Earth's crust. What is the force acting on Block B from Block A? Shouldn't it be the force of gravity acting on Block A because that force is pushing down on Block B?

Comment: FWIW: Besides feeling any forces due to Earth's gravity acting on itself, block B also feels the [_stress_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stress_(mechanics)) of being squeezed between the Earth and the weight of block A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the free body diagram:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Gravity is an attractive force, so we tend to think of it as "pulling" rather than "pushing". But you're right that block B experiences a gravitational force from A.

There is a second force. Block A doesn't fall through Block B, even though there's an attractive gravitational force – according to Newton's Second Law, it seems like it should. There must be a force acting on block A from block B (a contact force) to stop it accelerating. We call this the normal reaction force. You can think of it as the force that atoms experience not wanting to be squashed together. By Newton's Third Law, that means there's also a force from block A on block B (confusingly, the "equal and opposite reaction" to the "normal reaction").

If the blocks were electrically charged, there would be a further force, separate to these two.